# Find and replace with bracket in notepad++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

Here is the example data

```
nvarchar(5) null,
bigint not null,
nvarchar(5) null
```

if I'd like to replace `nvarchar(5) null` to be `nvarchar(255) null`

then I ctrl+H

Find what : `nvarchar(5) null`
Replace with : `nvarchar(255) null`

The result is `nvarchar255 null`, but I need to be `nvarchar(255) null`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the search dialog are three radio buttons for "Search mode". It sounds like you selected "Regular expression". You should select "Normal"  and try again.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous You should use "Normal" because in regular expression mode, the `(5)` is referring to a part of the match. But actually I just tested and I can't reproduce your issue with any of the settings. It's as if the "find what" is using normal mode and the "replace with" is using regular expressions - which shouldn't be possible